# how can I delete double entries of different column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates

with other form i have table like

```
rowsid     source_row   same_as_row 

row1       1                18    

row2       3                 18

row3       18                1

row4       18                3
```

i want only elimate  the rows3 and row4 :

```
row3       18                1

row4       18                3
```

which query! to delete query row3 and row4 .help

Comment: How did your data end up getting duplicated? It seems like deleting is a good idea, but what's stopping it from re-generating? (We also need more information such as how do you tell which row takes precedence?)

Comment: can you make a true example of what you really want to do? is that your table, really?

Comment: Why row 3 & 4 and not row 1 and 2? That is, how do you decide which of the duplicates to delete?

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM table 
GROUP BY sourcerow
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

It should do it, assuming you're only looking for duplicate values in `sourcerow` column

Comment: wrong sql, i dont want eleminate widht count(*) > 1, i want eleminate duplicata betweenn source_row   same_as_row

Comment: @AbdelillahFarka: so if there are rows with count(*) same_as_row > 1 delete ids described there?

Comment: Not going to downvote yet because the question is still unclear. But this query doesn't look right given the example rows the OP wanted to delete.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** : Well blow me down *(previous answer deleted)*

Since double nesting works, this is the way I'd do it (even though part of it is highly redundant from a logical standpoint)

```
DELETE
  yourTable
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM (SELECT same_as_row FROM yourTable GROUP BY same_as_row)) as lookup
    ON lookup.same_as_row = yourTable.source_row
WHERE
    source_row > same_as_row
```

Comment: You can use a sub query. You just need to double nest it into a derived table.

Comment: @MartinSmith : As per the edit?  If so, why does it work?  Something to do with scope?  Or because the deepest sub-query isn't correlated?

Comment: [Explained here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/). The derived table gets materialised into a temporary table implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    rowsid, source_row, same_as_row
from tablename t1
where not exists 
(
    select * from tablename t2
    where t2.source_row = t1.same_as_row and t2.same_as_row = t1.source_row and t1.rowsid > t2.rowsid)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM table 
GROUP BY rowsid, source_row, same_as_row
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1